# Calculating time in MM:SS:TSHSTS

Tags: python, optimization, time, datetime-conversion

So I'm working with time to format seconds to the format MM:SS:TSHSTS, meaning minutes:seconds:1/10 second 1/100 second 1/1000 second. This is basicly to calculate lap times for a racing simulator.

My input comes in seconds so for instance 124.6073 seconds -> 02:04:607.

I've produced this function and it works, I just want to know how can I optimize this since in my head this is kinda hammered as I couldn't think of something better at the time.

```
def convert_lap_times(seconds_per_lap):

minutes = seconds_per_lap // 60
seconds = seconds_per_lap % 60
rest = seconds_per_lap % 1
rest_str = str(rest).split('0.')
decimal_rest = rest_str[1]

return "%02i:%02i.%0.3s" % (minutes, seconds, decimal_rest)
```

So the rest is the decimal part of said number and all worked fine until that point. The "big" issue becomes when I want to get rid of the integer part, for instance 0.607, I just wanted 607 so I parsed it as a string... is there a better way?

Thanks a lot and all the best!

Comment: You can just use regular floating point formatting with the desired number of decimal-places for the value in `rest` — no need to convert it to a string manually like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
def convert_lap_times(seconds_per_lap):
    return "{:02.0f}:{:06.3f}".format(*divmod(seconds_per_lap,60))

print(convert_lap_times(124.6073))  # 02:04.607
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alain. Quick question thought, can you explain the format of {:xx} and the format(*divmod) XD thanks again! Cheers

Comment: Format string documentation can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp).  `{:02.0f}` is zero-filled (`0`), two positions(`2`), no-decimals(`.0`), fixed length float (`f`).  The divmod(...,60) will divide the number by 60 giving a quotient that corresponds to the number of munites and remaininder that are the seconds (both will be floats). The `*` before divmod unpacks the resulting tuple into parameters for the format method (so it gets two values correponding to the two `{...}` in the format string).

Comment: ahhhhh alright altight got it thanks a lot!! And btw, sorry for being lazy and not checking the documentation first! Cheers Alain